# Combining multiple WAV files into a single MP3

Tags: ubuntu, audio, libav

I'm trying to combine a number of wav files into a single mp3. The simplest command I can come up with is this:

```
/usr/bin/avconv \
-y \
-i input1.wav \
-i input2.wav \
-i input3.wav \
-i input4.wav \
-f mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 5 output.mp3
```

Which outputs this:

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr 10 2015 23:18:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'input1.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
  Duration: 00:00:05.03, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from 'input2.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
  Duration: 00:00:05.03, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #2.0 : stereo
Input #2, wav, from 'input3.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
  Duration: 00:00:05.03, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #2.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #3.0 : stereo
Input #3, wav, from 'input4.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
  Duration: 00:00:05.03, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #3.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le -> libmp3lame)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
size=      86kB time=5.04 bitrate= 139.3kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:84kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.479658%
```

It seems to recognize all the inputs and the output is written, however, the `output.mp3` only contains the contents of `input1.wav`.

How can I combine multiple wav files into a single mp3?

PS: I've tries the `concat` functionality [1] but it gives me the same result.

[1] https://libav.org/avconv.html#concat

Comment: Why don't u use some gui software?

Comment: Because it runs on a server.

Comment: Ups sorry about that